# Ruby-FFI: MemoryPointer.read_int present in 1.9, but not 1.8

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am writing a wrapper for a library with Ruby-FFI and trying to get it to work on Ruby 1.8 and 1.9

When I run it on 1.9, MemoryPointer has a method read_uint, but not when I run it on 1.8. Behold:

```
require 'ffi'
```

1.9

```
FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:uint).methods.sort #=> has :read_uint
```

1.8

```
FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:uint).methods.sort #=> no :read_uint
```

Is it not exactly the same package that gets installed with gems? But OK, this one requires some compilation. Even so, it's on the same box. Please help me understand.

Comment: Though it doesn't answer my question, I have come right by using the get_* and put_* methods of the MemoryPointer class. They cater for all the basic known C types, the only difference being that you need to specify an offset (mostly 0) in each call as the first parameter.